# Xamarin Forms - use OnIdiom to set an image within a carousel page

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Looking at the XAML below (which is an extract from a carousel page), is there any way to use OnIdiom to set the image gl_CarouselIndicator to different things for phone and tablet?

I have used OnIdiom many times but I'm unsure how I would structure it in this instance.

thanks

```
<local:SwipePageContent
            BackgroundImage="CRM.png" IconColor="#FFF" gl_CarouselIndicator="CarousellCounter1.png" 
            Header="{ artina:Translate page1Header }" 
            Text="{ artina:Translate page1Description }" 
            TextLine2="{ artina:Translate page1Text }" 
            PageIndex="0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be really easy, I just set it in code-behind

```
if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
{
       Page1.gl_CarouselIndicator = "CarouselCounterSmall.png";
}
else
{
        Page1.gl_CarouselIndicator = "CarousellCounter1.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set image source with device brands and type inside the xmal file:

```
<Image 
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  BackgroundColor="White"
  Aspect="AspectFit">

    <Image.Source>      
      <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                          iOS="logo.png"
                          Android="logo.png"
                          WinPhone="logo.png" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                          iOS="logo_iPad.png"
                          Android="logo.png"
                          WinPhone="logo.png" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
      </OnIdiom>
    </Image.Source>
```